# Gps LocationListenser for GoogleMaps V2 in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to understand the relationship between googlemaps `LatLng` and `Location class`. Are they convertable ? I am using

> GoogleMaps v2

in my application so How can I use my GPS To locate my position on maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` on your `GoogleMap` and then just call `getMyLocation()` periodically, if you wish. Otherwise, in addition to calling `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`, you can:

Step #1: Set up a `LocationListener` using `LocationManager`.

Step #2: Call `setLocationSource()` on your `GoogleMap`, supplying a `LocationSource` implementation

Step #3: In the `LocationSource` implementation, hold onto the listener object supplied to you in `activate()`

Step #4: When location fixes come into your `LocationListener`, pass them to the listener you were provided in `activate()`

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location) demonstrating this.